# Python Downloading files and images

Tags: python, image, download

There are couple of images and one word document in the given page source , and I am trying to install all of them  by matching them with the regex I wrote `"\w+\.\w{1,4}"`
is the regex suitable or not?

Is this piece of code right `retrieve = urllib.urlretrieve(i,'C:\Python27')`

Here is my code:

```
import sys, urllib, re

def retriev_files(page):
    open_page = urllib.urlopen(page)
    contents = open_page.read()
    find_files = re.findall("\w+\.\w{1,4}",contents)
    for i in find_files:
        try:
            print " retrieving %s ... " %i
            retrieve = urllib.urlretrieve(i,'C:\Python27')
            print " done !! "
            return retrieve

        except urllib.urlretrieve as err:
            pass

def main():
    print retriev_files("http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40001507/CSN08115/cw_webpage/index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

- your regex will capture anything which is some characters followed by a followed by one or more characters, that might icon_clown.gif but also r.macf which is part of the email address. Have a look at this famous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) here to get an idea why RegEx is not a good approach for parsing HTML. Try something like beautifulsoup or preferably Selenium for getting data from web pages.
- `return retrieve` will only retrieve the first image and then exit your function. You could define a list `retrieved_images`, then use `retrieved_images.append(retrieve[0])` and finally return the list
- [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) returns a tuple where the first element is the filename (the reason for `[0]` in the line above). The second argument needs to be a filename and not a path.
- Your regex would find some filenames, e.g. it would work for `icon_clown.gif`, but it doesn't give you the full path, i.e. you would need to merge the URL from `page` with your RegEx match, e.g.

The following line might work for most cases, e.g. when only the relative image URL is given.

```
urllib.urlretrieve(path[0:path.rfind('/')] + '/' file)
```